# Help find a usecase to understand sql vs nosql issue

Tags: database-design, mongodb, nosql

I have very little background in SQL (one pet project with PostgreSQL that demonstrated only basic queries up to joins) and no experience at all with NoSQL. I understand that there are many DB architectures that get labeled NoSQL, I'm primarily looking for document-based SQL alternatives like MongoDB, which ***APPARENTLY*** are better suited for quick takeoff when you are building a prototype fast and are the most general purpose among other NoSQL tools.

I'm willing to do a research by making an identical application twice - with these two DB paradigms under the hood, and I need help to find a good idea that would help me highlight the differences. I've spent several hours looking for differences on the internet, but all the articles I found seem to just scratch the surface and explain HOW TO USE either SQL or NoSQL instead of when NOT to use each on explicit usecases.

I'm tired of reading the same material all over again and want to get some hands on experience, but ***I'm very afraid*** that everything I'll come up with would ***just as well*** work with both paradigms, and I will be just unable to understand any difference after I've written the example, because I'll have no trouble implementing. I need some ideas what I can do with each of these but not with its opponent. Could you point me in some better direction than I am heading now? :)

Comment: Welcome to dba.SE.  This is a bit broad and likely to result answers that are opinion-based rather than fact based.  Can you edit your question to focus on a specific scenario or issue you're trying to resolve?

Comment: @bbaird Unfortunately, that is as focused as I can make it... In this case if I'm looking for general advice where to start I now think asking this on stack exchange was not the best option. However I'll leave it open, I think I might get something out of even opinionated answers. If I'll get downvoted then so be it :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You might find [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287383/if-nosql-stands-for-not-only-sql-is-sql-a-subset-of-nosql/287388#287388) of interest also! Interesting that you should mention PostgreSQL - the classic RDBMS and NoSQL are not necessarily mutually exclusive in the case of this particular (amazing...) server. With it you can `pick-n-mix` queries with classic tabular fields and JSONB and performance is pretty good - check a few links [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=postgresql+vs+mongodb+performance+2020).

Comment: Thanks! I think questions mentioned above are quite exhaustive. Closing the question for now